# Default Record Type based on User Profile

Tags: opportunity, profile, record-type, user-profile

Opportunities on my org have more than one record type. How do I see the default record type that will be used when a specific profile makes a new opportunity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each profile, one can see the default record types as:

Setup> Profiles> Object Settings> Select Opportunity Object> and there you see all the record types and the one that is marked as default.